# How to work with Interface builder and Rubymotion. Workflow

Tags: rubymotion

I am building an iOS app using Rubymotion. I am constructing the UI with the help of Interfaceb Builder. In the screen that I am working on I got the following elements:

1. Navbar
2. Label
3. TableView

I am populating the tableview via an API call. All works fine but I am not sure I am doing things like I am supposed to do. From what I can understand IB is only used to "draw" the UI instead of coding it, nothing more?

This is my controller code. Again, it works fine but I think I am not following "best practice".

http://pastie.org/5368976

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways of figuring out how you want to build your views.

If you are not doing a crazy amount of custom designed UI, then I don't see why I would not use something like [@colinta's](https://github.com/colinta) [Teacup](https://github.com/rubymotion/teacup).

I would avoid using storyboards to build a UI. Please see the thread [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rubymotion/eullUwYr23U/5DjdXFPew9QJ).

On that note, don't hesitate to check out the discussions on the [Ruby Motion Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rubymotion) if you can't find the answers on SO. The group seems very active.

Also, IRC: irc.freenode.net, #rubymotion